# Transferring From Australia Visit Visa to other AU visa

Tags: visa, working-visas, australia

I would like to know if I go to Australia on visit visa (600), can I change to another visa (e.g. work permit-457) while I will be on visit visa inside Australia ? or Do I have to go outside of Australia and apply for a new visa ?

Comment: Would be interested to hear what you ended up doing regarding your visa!

Answer (score 2):

Your employer can always apply for a 457 visa onshore or offshore. But if you are given the `Condition 8503 - No further stay` on your visit visa, then you may have to leave the country and come back in. You can also apply for a Bridging Visa A if you do not intend to leave the country and are confident that your 457 will be granted. As always, please do take a second opinion from either an Immigration Lawyer to confirm the above.

Comment: Any idea, if the "No further stay" condition can apply to eVisitor visas (subclass 651) as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can - **under certain requirements** - apply for this visa inside Australia.

However, in contrast to @deppfx statement you are **NOT** even allowed to apply for this if you have the `No further stay` condition on your visa. It is not just about leaving the country and returning.

Information on visa subclass 457 is available here: https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/457-

Quotes:

> [...]
>
> You cannot apply for this visa if you already hold another visa that
>   has a ‘No further stay’ condition.
>
> [...]
>
> If you apply for this visa in Australia, you could be eligible for a
>   Bridging visa that allows you to stay in the country lawfully while
>   your application is processed. If you are given a Bridging visa A, you
>   can apply for a [Bridging visa B (BVB)](https://www.border.gov.au/Visas/Pages/020-Bridging-Visa-B-BVB.aspx) to travel outside Australia
>   while you wait for a decision.
>
> [...]

Information regarding the `No further stay condition` can be found here:
http://www.border.gov.au/about/corporate/information/fact-sheets/52b-nfc

Quote:

> Condition 8503 is a mandatory condition of the following visas:
>
> 1. Visitor visa (subclass 600) for the following streams:
>
>    - sponsored family stream
>    - approved destination status scheme stream    operating out of the People's Republic of China
>    - tourist stream for applicants who have sponsorship imposed on them
> 2. Training and Research visa (subclass 402) for the professional development stream only
> 3. Work and Holiday visa (subclass 462) if you have previously held two subclass 462 visas.

You can also check if your visa contains such conditions here:
http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/check-your-visa-and-work-entitlements